# Slide contents from one div into the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a markup arranged as follows in my website:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="middle">
        <div class="red-container">
            <div class="row">
                Middle. Row 1.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div class="green-container">
            <div class="row">
                Right. Row 1.
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

The `right` div as would be obvious has to be towards the right of the `middle` div.
Here's the fiddle (`right` div here inside my fiddle somehow is not actually to the right of `middle` div) : http://jsfiddle.net/NNMYS/

I am trying to achieve a sliding effect here: 
All the content from the `middle` div should slide to the left and get removed after the animation. On the other hand, simultaneously, the content from the `right` div (which in my case will be added by ajax to the `right` div) should slide from the right `div` to the `middle` div (and removed from the `right` div). How can that be done?

I could have done a content slider directly by having all the content directly placed separated by positions and sliding to the clicked item. But here since I would be adding content by ajax and also have some responsive implementation, in my case that doesn't seem to possible.

Comment: So, just to be sure. You want the content of the div to slide and not the actual color?

Comment: @Niklas : It should be everything in the right div which means the color as well. Which means the whole `green-container` should be removed from `right` div and green-container itself has that color, so that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1):

Look at this.  I think this might help

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/